# Shell - calling function with nc -c

Tags: shell, netcat

This is my Server-Code for now.
I just want to get Data from a Client, analyze it and send my answer.
Is there a way to call my function managedata() in nc? My Code, obviously doesn't work.

server.sh:

```
managedata()
{
echo $1
#do something with data
return $1
}

listen()
{
echo "Server listening.."
nc -l -p 1234 -c '$(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)'
}

#MAIN
while true;
do
listen
done
```

Client.sh:

```
send()
{
echo $1 | nc $ip $port -o 0
}

#
register()
{
read -p "Login: " usrname
echo -n "Password: "
read -s password | shasum > password

#Schleife zum encrypten des Passworts
#Count = n -> Leslie Lamport Alogrithmus
n=5
count=$n
while [ $count -ge 2 ]
do
    password="$(cat password | shasum)"
    ((count--))
done

password=`cat password`
echo
echo $password

data="reg-$usrname-$n-$password"

send $data
}

#
log()
{
echo "..."
}

#
menue()
{
echo "====== Lab: Shell Programming (BS) ======"
echo "  r   Register"
echo "  l   Login"
echo "  q   Quit"
echo

read -p "your choice: " check

case "$check" in
    r) register;;
    l) log;;
    q) exit;;
esac

}


#MAIN
ip=$1
port=$2

while true
do
menue
done
```

bash -x server.sh:

```
+ true
+ listen
+ echo 'Server listening..'
Server listening..
+ nc -l -p 1234 -c '$(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)'
sh: 1: managedata: not found
+ true
+ listen
+ echo 'Server listening..'
Server listening..
+ nc -l -p 1234 -c '$(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)'
```

Comment: do you meant to pass `$i` to `managedata` when doing that `managedata $i` ?

Comment: That was the intention yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you should "tell" `bash` to treat `managedata` as command or function that can be executed.
BTW, you need to use `$()` to execute whole expression not only `managedata`:

```
nc -l -p 1234 -c $(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)
```

Also bash can't return strings, only integer error codes, so `return $1` won't work if it's not integer in range of 0 - 255.

Replace to `return 0`

Comment: Now I'm getting "Connection refused" on Client-Side

Comment: @Soody What is the output of `$(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)` ?

Comment: If I use `nc -l -p 1234 -c '$(read i && managedata $i && echo $?)'`
I once again get "managedata: not found"

Comment: @Soody Ok, can you execute your sell script as follows: `bash -x your_script.sh`

Comment: @Soody as well remove single quotes before and after `$()`

Comment: The first block of code in my post is `myscript.sh`..
If I remove the quotes the server wants to read input from the console

Comment: @Soody indeed, that what read supposed to do...but what did you expected?

Comment: It should read the incoming Data from the Client. If i do `nc -l -p 1234 -c 'read i && echo $i'` it reads the input and sends it back

Comment: @Soody, ah got it, you can't return string in bash - `return $1` will not work. Updating my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113655/discussion-between-samuel-and-soody).

Comment: This is just patently wrong - this answer explains how to pass the results output of managedata as a parameter to nc, instead of how to run managedata as part of nc's handler.